# highcharts gantt display as bar instead of lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts, gantt-chart

I want to make a chart that display on a horizontal bar some time intervals. 
I managed to do that but I got stuck on how it displays it.
Now each segment is displayed as a line with 2 delimiters(looking as circles) at start and end of the segment.
Since there are a lot  of events within the graph i cannot distinguish the events, mostly I get a continuos bar created by the delimiters/circles.

What I would like to do is to represent each segment as a vertical line that will be as wide as the duration of the event without delimiters, like this I could distinguish the activities.

I searched a lot on the internet and tried to change the plot display type to bar, but didn't helped.

My code is:

```
    var tasks = [{
                 name:'336',
                 intervals:[{from:1393565701000,to:1393565762000},{from:1393565776000,to:1393565829000},{from:1393565841000,to:1393565881000},{from:1393565892000,to:1393565958000},{from:1393565982000,to:1393566094000},{from:1393566112000,to:1393566120000},{from:1393566186000,to:1393566232000},{from:1393566244000,to:1393566312000},{from:1393566320000,to:1393566398000},{from:1393566415000,to:1393566490000},{from:1393566509000,to:1393566555000},{from:1393566564000,to:1393566625000},{from:1393566637000,to:1393566739000},{from:1393566755000,to:1393566841000},{from:1393566869000,to:1393566971000},{from:1393567013000,to:1393567091000},{from:1393567102000,to:1393567128000},{from:1393567147000,to:1393567233000},{from:1393567247000,to:1393567342000},{from:1393567360000,to:1393567438000},{from:1393567455000,to:1393567477000},{from:1393567503000,to:1393567550000},{from:1393567562000,to:1393567614000},{from:1393567641000,to:1393567723000},{from:1393567779000,to:1393567869000},{from:1393567883000,to:1393567968000},{from:1393567984000,to:1393567997000},{from:1393568005000,to:1393568058000},{from:1393568078000,to:1393568124000},{from:1393568148000,to:1393568246000},{from:1393568260000,to:1393568324000},{from:1393568351000,to:1393568437000},{from:1393568449000,to:1393568546000},{from:1393568557000,to:1393568640000},{from:1393568653000,to:1393568692000},{from:1393568721000,to:1393568787000},{from:1393568817000,to:1393568835000},{from:1393568860000,to:1393568903000},{from:1393568923000,to:1393569009000},{from:1393569023000,to:1393569112000},{from:1393569132000,to:1393569196000},{from:1393569235000,to:1393569304000},{from:1393569319000,to:1393569335000},{from:1393569373000,to:1393569384000},{from:1393569709000,to:1393569789000},{from:1393569813000,to:1393569903000},{from:1393569916000,to:1393569979000},{from:1393570007000,to:1393570060000},{from:1393570086000,to:1393570090000},{from:1393570108000,to:1393570137000},{from:1393570153000,to:1393570183000},{from:1393570207000,to:1393570275000},{from:1393570291000,to:1393570338000},{from:1393570351000,to:1393570488000},{from:1393570522000,to:1393570584000},{from:1393570597000,to:1393570636000},{from:1393570661000,to:1393570776000},{from:1393570826000,to:1393570839000},{from:1393570864000,to:1393570957000},{from:1393570972000,to:1393571064000},{from:1393571079000,to:1393571155000},{from:1393571175000,to:1393571255000},{from:1393571268000,to:1393571363000},{from:1393571449000,to:1393571560000},{from:1393571589000,to:1393571610000},{from:1393571659000,to:1393571679000},{from:1393571707000,to:1393571733000},{from:1393571755000,to:1393571814000},{from:1393571830000,to:1393571883000},{from:1393571897000,to:1393571932000},{from:1393571948000,to:1393571959000},{from:1393571972000,to:1393572004000},{from:1393572013000,to:1393572082000},{from:1393572103000,to:1393572131000},{from:1393572153000,to:1393572214000},{from:1393572221000,to:1393572236000},{from:1393572247000,to:1393572261000},{from:1393572276000,to:1393572294000},{from:1393572308000,to:1393572325000},{from:1393572339000,to:1393572363000},{from:1393572419000,to:1393572442000},{from:1393572458000,to:1393572498000},{from:1393572509000,to:1393572551000},{from:1393572564000,to:1393572574000},{from:1393572587000,to:1393572612000},{from:1393572621000,to:1393572657000},{from:1393572672000,to:1393572678000},{from:1393572689000,to:1393572708000},{from:1393572721000,to:1393572805000},{from:1393572828000,to:1393572848000},{from:1393572871000,to:1393572876000},{from:1393572891000,to:1393572921000},{from:1393572931000,to:1393572957000},{from:1393572977000,to:1393572990000},{from:1393573004000,to:1393573046000},{from:1393573057000,to:1393573082000},{from:1393573303000,to:1393573307000},{from:1393573321000,to:1393573345000},{from:1393573387000,to:1393573399000},{from:1393573410000,to:1393573415000},{from:1393573435000,to:1393573483000},{from:1393573501000,to:1393573566000},{from:1393573580000,to:1393573593000},{from:1393573601000,to:1393573628000},{from:1393573641000,to:1393573651000},{from:1393573659000,to:1393573690000},{from:1393573704000,to:1393573716000},{from:1393573726000,to:1393573791000},{from:1393573805000,to:1393573899000},{from:1393573913000,to:1393573924000},{from:1393573936000,to:1393573938000},{from:1393573957000,to:1393573973000},{from:1393573989000,to:1393574021000},{from:1393574047000,to:1393574056000},{from:1393574070000,to:1393574077000},{from:1393574094000,to:1393574125000},{from:1393574167000,to:1393574212000},{from:1393574236000,to:1393574241000},{from:1393574253000,to:1393574277000},{from:1393574371000,to:1393574381000},{from:1393574400000,to:1393574428000},{from:1393574460000,to:1393574493000},{from:1393574515000,to:1393574535000},{from:1393574547000,to:1393574584000},{from:1393574614000,to:1393574624000},{from:1393574636000,to:1393574681000},{from:1393574691000,to:1393574713000},{from:1393574725000,to:1393574758000},{from:1393574788000,to:1393574819000},{from:1393574850000,to:1393574861000},{from:1393574876000,to:1393574883000},{from:1393574900000,to:1393574908000},{from:1393574940000,to:1393574951000},{from:1393574967000,to:1393575040000},{from:1393575056000,to:1393575078000},{from:1393575096000,to:1393575121000},{from:1393575137000,to:1393575189000},{from:1393575205000,to:1393575261000},{from:1393575278000,to:1393575317000},{from:1393575329000,to:1393575342000},{from:1393575389000,to:1393575405000},{from:1393575446000,to:1393575475000},{from:1393575490000,to:1393575542000},{from:1393575558000,to:1393575570000},{from:1393575596000,to:1393575626000},{from:1393575644000,to:1393575689000},{from:1393575701000,to:1393575741000},{from:1393575763000,to:1393575774000},{from:1393575789000,to:1393575818000},{from:1393575854000,to:1393575860000},{from:1393575889000,to:1393575905000},{from:1393575918000,to:1393575930000},{from:1393575942000,to:1393575962000},{from:1393575983000,to:1393576024000},{from:1393576040000,to:1393576059000},{from:1393576073000,to:1393576127000},{from:1393576142000,to:1393576187000},{from:1393576213000,to:1393576281000},{from:1393576310000,to:1393576337000},{from:1393576352000,to:1393576416000},{from:1393576458000,to:1393576478000},{from:1393576490000,to:1393576519000},{from:1393576529000,to:1393576579000},{from:1393576592000,to:1393576600000},{from:1393576609000,to:1393576660000},{from:1393576670000,to:1393576689000},{from:1393576703000,to:1393576721000},{from:1393576759000,to:1393576780000},{from:1393576787000,to:1393576829000},{from:1393577212000,to:1393577253000},{from:1393577273000,to:1393577275000},{from:1393577292000,to:1393577354000},{from:1393577372000,to:1393577393000},{from:1393577407000,to:1393577433000},{from:1393577463000,to:1393577479000},{from:1393577501000,to:1393577521000},{from:1393577536000,to:1393577601000},{from:1393577622000,to:1393577685000},{from:1393577701000,to:1393577711000},{from:1393577736000,to:1393577784000},{from:1393577798000,to:1393577819000},{from:1393577860000,to:1393577883000},{from:1393577901000,to:1393577994000},{from:1393578032000,to:1393578033000},{from:1393578056000,to:1393578078000},{from:1393578094000,to:1393578159000},{from:1393578172000,to:1393578189000},{from:1393578204000,to:1393578284000},{from:1393578311000,to:1393578356000},{from:1393578367000,to:1393578437000},{from:1393578449000,to:1393578509000},{from:1393578519000,to:1393578549000},{from:1393578572000,to:1393578637000},{from:1393578649000,to:1393578657000},{from:1393578674000,to:1393578716000},{from:1393578728000,to:1393578793000},{from:1393578808000,to:1393578879000},{from:1393578891000,to:1393578908000},{from:1393578922000,to:1393578949000},{from:1393578961000,to:1393579006000},{from:1393579031000,to:1393579045000},{from:1393579068000,to:1393579108000},{from:1393579122000,to:1393579167000},{from:1393579187000,to:1393579216000},{from:1393579225000,to:1393579257000},{from:1393579275000,to:1393579290000},{from:1393579305000,to:1393579397000},{from:1393579418000,to:1393579477000},{from:1393579490000,to:1393579520000},{from:1393579532000,to:1393579571000},{from:1393579583000,to:1393579589000},{from:1393579651000,to:1393579667000},{from:1393579677000,to:1393579690000},{from:1393579712000,to:1393579729000},{from:1393579743000,to:1393579764000},{from:1393583314000,to:1393583355000},{from:1393583365000,to:1393583373000},{from:1393583388000,to:1393583485000},{from:1393583515000,to:1393583534000},{from:1393583562000,to:1393583591000},{from:1393583604000,to:1393583634000},{from:1393583659000,to:1393583675000},{from:1393583691000,to:1393583887000},{from:1393583914000,to:1393583932000},{from:1393583948000,to:1393583964000},{from:1393583987000,to:1393583991000},{from:1393584039000,to:1393584085000},{from:1393584107000,to:1393584133000},{from:1393584151000,to:1393584165000},{from:1393584178000,to:1393584270000},{from:1393584288000,to:1393584342000},{from:1393584353000,to:1393584367000},{from:1393584385000,to:1393584440000},{from:1393584459000,to:1393584490000},{from:1393584500000,to:1393584516000},{from:1393584526000,to:1393584575000},{from:1393584590000,to:1393584664000},{from:1393584684000,to:1393584749000},{from:1393584762000,to:1393584827000},{from:1393584843000,to:1393584871000},{from:1393584908000,to:1393584960000},{from:1393584970000,to:1393585003000},{from:1393585014000,to:1393585034000},{from:1393585063000,to:1393585121000},{from:1393585139000,to:1393585148000},{from:1393585178000,to:1393585249000},{from:1393585258000,to:1393585294000},{from:1393585304000,to:1393585396000},{from:1393585414000,to:1393585458000},{from:1393585471000,to:1393585489000},{from:1393585517000,to:1393585582000},{from:1393585613000,to:1393585634000},{from:1393585648000,to:1393585661000},{from:1393585680000,to:1393585712000},{from:1393585724000,to:1393585740000},{from:1393585752000,to:1393585769000},{from:1393585785000,to:1393585825000},{from:1393585829000,to:1393585859000},{from:1393585907000,to:1393585933000},{from:1393585966000,to:1393585999000},{from:1393586054000,to:1393586088000},{from:1393586096000,to:1393586120000},{from:1393586146000,to:1393586207000},{from:1393586238000,to:1393586270000},{from:1393586281000,to:1393586282000},{from:1393586293000,to:1393586299000},{from:1393586316000,to:1393586318000},{from:1393586350000,to:1393586360000},{from:1393586431000,to:1393586435000},{from:1393586504000,to:1393586515000},{from:1393586536000,to:1393586563000},{from:1393586575000,to:1393586593000},{from:1393586625000,to:1393586708000},{from:1393586727000,to:1393586736000},{from:1393586757000,to:1393586803000},{from:1393586824000,to:1393586843000},{from:1393586881000,to:1393586890000},{from:1393586916000,to:1393587008000},{from:1393587028000,to:1393587040000},{from:1393587066000,to:1393587103000},{from:1393587116000,to:1393587133000},{from:1393587170000,to:1393587191000},{from:1393587205000,to:1393587246000},{from:1393587263000,to:1393587356000},{from:1393587651000,to:1393587693000},{from:1393587713000,to:1393587729000},{from:1393587749000,to:1393587812000},{from:1393587825000,to:1393587879000},{from:1393587891000,to:1393587966000},{from:1393587992000,to:1393588025000},{from:1393588045000,to:1393588078000},{from:1393588090000,to:1393588092000},{from:1393588107000,to:1393588137000},{from:1393588148000,to:1393588215000},{from:1393588238000,to:1393588307000},{from:1393588329000,to:1393588388000},{from:1393588398000,to:1393588446000},{from:1393588465000,to:1393588514000},{from:1393588536000,to:1393588574000},{from:1393588589000,to:1393588605000},{from:1393588619000,to:1393588688000},{from:1393588729000,to:1393588821000},{from:1393588834000,to:1393588843000},{from:1393588859000,to:1393588897000},{from:1393588912000,to:1393588921000},{from:1393588937000,to:1393588981000},{from:1393588991000,to:1393589011000},{from:1393589032000,to:1393589062000},{from:1393589076000,to:1393589112000},{from:1393589128000,to:1393589129000},{from:1393589151000,to:1393589177000},{from:1393589190000,to:1393589222000},{from:1393589233000,to:1393589261000},{from:1393589274000,to:1393589315000},{from:1393589335000,to:1393589379000},{from:1393589391000,to:1393589421000},{from:1393589628000,to:1393589718000},{from:1393589736000,to:1393589784000},{from:1393589796000,to:1393589839000},{from:1393589850000,to:1393589935000},{from:1393589952000,to:1393589962000},{from:1393589973000,to:1393589990000},{from:1393590973000,to:1393591009000},{from:1393591020000,to:1393591080000},{from:1393591089000,to:1393591153000},{from:1393591161000,to:1393591214000},{from:1393591222000,to:1393591262000},{from:1393591304000,to:1393591396000},{from:1393591408000,to:1393591416000},{from:1393591427000,to:1393591430000},{from:1393591445000,to:1393591498000},{from:1393591507000,to:1393591562000},{from:1393591571000,to:1393591585000},{from:1393591598000,to:1393591658000},{from:1393591679000,to:1393591720000},{from:1393591739000,to:1393591764000},{from:1393591772000,to:1393591795000},{from:1393591802000,to:1393591900000},{from:1393591913000,to:1393592009000},{from:1393592023000,to:1393592066000},{from:1393592073000,to:1393592109000},{from:1393592118000,to:1393592196000},{from:1393592210000,to:1393592248000},{from:1393592259000,to:1393592334000},{from:1393592345000,to:1393592355000},{from:1393592416000,to:1393592423000},{from:1393592440000,to:1393592513000},{from:1393592521000,to:1393592545000},{from:1393592556000,to:1393592602000},{from:1393592642000,to:1393592643000},{from:1393592661000,to:1393592679000},{from:1393592704000,to:1393592739000},{from:1393592749000,to:1393592839000},{from:1393592853000,to:1393592945000},{from:1393592960000,to:1393593026000},{from:1393593039000,to:1393593120000},{from:1393593134000,to:1393593158000},{from:1393593173000,to:1393593199000},{from:1393593206000,to:1393593234000},{from:1393593261000,to:1393593278000},{from:1393593287000,to:1393593290000},{from:1393593340000,to:1393593370000},{from:1393593382000,to:1393593437000},{from:1393593449000,to:1393593505000},{from:1393593526000,to:1393593580000},{from:1393593599000,to:1393593619000},{from:1393593634000,to:1393593679000},{from:1393593689000,to:1393593726000},{from:1393593737000,to:1393593779000},{from:1393593795000,to:1393593832000},{from:1393593840000,to:1393593874000},{from:1393593889000,to:1393593933000},{from:1393593950000,to:1393593990000},{from:1393594000000,to:1393594005000},{from:1393594022000,to:1393594064000},{from:1393594082000,to:1393594140000},{from:1393594169000,to:1393594184000},{from:1393594195000,to:1393594224000},{from:1393594232000,to:1393594308000},{from:1393594316000,to:1393594337000},{from:1393594344000,to:1393594398000},{from:1393594408000,to:1393594449000},{from:1393594460000,to:1393594485000},{from:1393594492000,to:1393594584000},{from:1393594601000,to:1393594636000},{from:1393594651000,to:1393594668000},{from:1393594874000,to:1393594933000},{from:1393594945000,to:1393594997000},{from:1393595007000,to:1393595098000},{from:1393595109000,to:1393595167000},{from:1393595174000,to:1393595238000},{from:1393595268000,to:1393595281000},{from:1393595290000,to:1393595382000},{from:1393595397000,to:1393595414000},{from:1393595427000,to:1393595452000},{from:1393595471000,to:1393595534000},{from:1393595548000,to:1393595577000},{from:1393595604000,to:1393595651000},{from:1393595674000,to:1393595710000},{from:1393595719000,to:1393595743000},{from:1393595752000,to:1393595811000},{from:1393595827000,to:1393595889000},{from:1393596027000,to:1393596043000},{from:1393596057000,to:1393596104000},{from:1393596112000,to:1393596120000},{from:1393596140000,to:1393596182000},{from:1393596191000,to:1393596222000},{from:1393596235000,to:1393596243000},{from:1393596281000,to:1393596306000},{from:1393596328000,to:1393596410000},{from:1393596429000,to:1393596505000},{from:1393596538000,to:1393596568000},{from:1393596623000,to:1393596680000},{from:1393596696000,to:1393596740000},{from:1393597205000,to:1393597285000},{from:1393597296000,to:1393597349000},{from:1393597364000,to:1393597455000},{from:1393597470000,to:1393597486000},{from:1393597500000,to:1393597506000},{from:1393597518000,to:1393597569000},{from:1393597591000,to:1393597650000},{from:1393597663000,to:1393597695000},{from:1393597704000,to:1393597743000},{from:1393597762000,to:1393597763000},{from:1393597777000,to:1393597789000},]
                 }];


var series = [];
$.each(tasks.reverse(), function(i, task) {
    var item = {
        name: task.name,
        data: []
    };
    $.each(task.intervals, function(j, interval) {
        item.data.push({
            x: interval.from,
            y: i,
            label: interval.label,
            from: interval.from,
            to: interval.to
        }, {
            x: interval.to,
            y: i,
            from: interval.from,
            to: interval.to
        });


        if (task.intervals[j + 1]) {
            item.data.push(
                [(interval.to + task.intervals[j + 1].from) / 2, null]
            );
        }

    });

    series.push(item);
});
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            timezoneOffset: -2 * 60
        },
        colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                    [1, 'rgb(240, 240, 255)']
                ]
            }
    ,
            borderWidth: 2,
            plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)',
            plotShadow: true,
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        }
    });

// create the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        spacingRight: 20,
        renderTo: 'container336',
        type: 'line',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Extension: qweqweq'
    },
            credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'

    },

    yAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        lineColor: '#FF0000',
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                if (tasks[this.value]) {
                    return tasks[this.value].name;
                }
            }
        },
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Calls'
        }

    },


    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return ((this.point.options.to-this.point.options.from)/1000) + ' seconds'; 
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            turboThreshold:20000
        },

        line: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            stacking: 'null',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'left',
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: series,
    dashStyle: 'shortdot'
```

I made also a jsfiddle for a better understanding and a visual explanation here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SwCnP/

Any ideea or solution is highly appreciated. I really got stuck with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to do the graph, but not using highcharts.
I used Rgraph multi events gantt library and was able to format the graph to my exact needs.
Thanks for the help, at least the answer motivated me to forget about using highcharts.

Answer (score 2):

Please take look at the examples

- http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/LnAq3/2/
- http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/2034/
- http://jsfiddle.net/LnAq3/11/ `grouping:false`

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, indeed i have tried with the examples you provided, and I understand (I hope) now I need to use as chart.type: columnrange. I made few attempts, I even found something similar here: http://jsfiddle.net/XBmB5/2/ that I wanted to apply to my scenario, but either I am too close to this to figure it out either I approached it wrong in the first place. In this example I just wanted to change the data source (series) with the var that I create in my script and show only one bar with the results, as in this specific graph type.  Failed http://jsfiddle.net/7sZaR/

Comment: Maybe if I rephrase my issue, will help in understanding. How can I group all the values within a series to show in the same bar/column

Comment: Each data points is positioned on single tick, but its possible to prepare mockup ?

Comment: graphic simple example: http://s17.postimg.org/u8j10fhzz/gantt.png In the initial example I posted I had data ranges that were displayed as line with delimiter points, if possible to remove the delimiter points and to increase the line size I think the visual effect will be improved, or the best way to show it as bar.

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of chart is not supported, you can try to set only pointWidth (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth) but im not sure if it will solve your problem.

Comment: Any suggestion on what other framework I could use that support this ?